# Migrate from TFS 2010 to Azure DevOps online

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-migration, azure-devops-migration-tools

I want to migrate form TFS 2010 to Azure DevOps online and was following `Azure DevOps Migration Guide.pdf` and running into issues when trying to validate my project collection.

On the other hand I had to see other MSFT documentation and it tells a different path:
[image]

Where as Azure DevOps Migration Guide says:
[image]

What is the best way to migrate from TFS 2010 to Azure DevOps online ?

Answer (score 1):

Look closely. One document is more recent than the other. The first screenshot shows Azure DevOps Server 2020 as the end point. The other shows TFS 2018.

You need to upgrade to the most recent version of Azure DevOps Server in order to migrate to Azure DevOps cloud. The "best way" is always to **follow the most recent official documentation**.

If you're looking for help with performing the migration, you need to ask a new question that asks a specific question about the issue you're encountering.

Comment: If you look more closely, the migration paths are different:
#1 - 2010 => 2013 => 2015 => Newest Version
#2 - 2010 => 2013 => Newest Version

Comment: 2015 is skipped altogether in #2

Comment: @VidhyaSagarReddy Yes, TFS 2018 supported upgrades from TFS 2013. Azure DevOps Server 2020 doesn't. That's why my answer says to follow the most recent documentation.

Comment: so, to move to Azure DevOps online, should I migrate till 2020 Server and then run migration tool there ?

Comment: @VidhyaSagarReddy yes, as per the latest documentation.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend that you use [data migration tool](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/migrate/) to [migrate data from Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Services.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops)

The data migration tool for Azure DevOps supports the two latest releases of Azure DevOps Server at a given time. Releases include updates and major releases. Currently the following versions of Azure DevOps Server are supported for import:

1. Azure DevOps Server 2019.1.1
2. Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1

Please update your TFS version and then Migrate your server to Azure DevOps